# Media Player Issue Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am having major problems with Android media player, I can't seem to play media files (.mp3) from a raw folder in resources. I have the following code:

```
private void playSound(String location) {
    try {
        Uri mp3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/raw/" + location);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, mp3);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Every time I try to run this code I get the following in log cat:

```
11-26 21:28:55.196: E/MediaPlayer(19441): error (1, -2147483648)
11-26 21:28:55.200: E/MediaPlayer(19441): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

---

I have also tried the following code as well:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mp3);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But every time I run that code, I get the following error:

```
11-26 21:33:26.765: E/MediaPlayer(19813): Should have subtitle controller already set
```

I have looked into this and it seems like there is an issue with Android 5.0 and the media player, but I really need a solution to this issue and so far I have had no luck. Has anyone come across one or both of these issues before? If so which had the best solution?

Thanks.

Comment: suggestion from the top of my head. try to set the media player volume `mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f)`, in conjunction with your second implementation.

Comment: Another quick suggestion because I'm not 100% sure this will fix your problem, try to change the uri in your first implementation to this `Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.audioFileToPlay);`, where audioFileToPlay is the resource id.

Comment: I have tested the app on two more devices now and found that a Nexus 5 running 5.0 is the only device that is having these issues. It looks like there is an issue with 5.0

Comment: can you play the same mp3 file from outside your app, using an external app?

Comment: me too, android5 with nexus5 error can't play background music

Comment: Have a look at this: [link](http://github.com/avafab/URLMediaPlayer)